# Stream content form pipe with Apache2

Tags: http, stream, apache2, pipe

Is it possible to write an Apache2 service that can pipe content to the client at is being generated?

I would like to setup a simple http service that triggers a build and immediately starts sending stdout (gcc stuff) to the client while the compiling is going on. The goal is that a client can use e.g. curl to test a build:

```
curl http://myserver.com/testbuild -F "file=@mypkg.tar.gz"
```

And immediately get to see stdout from the build process on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be possible somehow [using a cgi script](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/simple-cgi-and-apache-examples-on-ubuntu-linux), but the trick is to immediately get the stdout, bypassing the buffering. If you do not really need http as a transport protocol, why not use direct tcp streaming via [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).

On the build server you run a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do
nc -l -p 8080 -e /path/to/buildscript
done
```

and when any client connects via

```
nc <buildservername or ip> 8080
```

it gets the build stout immediately.

My recommendation would be something different (using [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org%20) as ci server, I do this even on a cubietruck), but for a quick and small solution, it should be enough. If you need http, you can even get this adding the http header to your build script.